# Does OAuth.tools provide any kind of API?

Tags: api, oauth, oauth.tools

I am wondering if [OAuth.tools](https://oauth.tools) provides any sort of API to control its functionality. Does it provide an API?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth.tools is almost-entirely a client-side web application that runs entirely in the user's browser. This is a really important aspect of its design considering the kind of data it works with. This kind of design doesn't lend itself to programability in the traditional API sense.

That said, you can provide a JWT on the hash of the URL. This will open all existing flows, and add a new JWT decode flow with the provided token. The format of the URL is this:

`https://oauth.tools/#jwt=$JWT`

An example would be [this](https://oauth.tools/#jwt=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkYW5pZWwiLCJpc3MiOiJhc3NlcnRpb24tY2xpZW50IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODQ0My9kZXYvb2F1dGgvdG9rZW4iLCJuYmYiOjE1MzU4MDY5MDUsImV4cCI6MTg4ODgwNjkwNSwiaWF0IjoxNTM1ODA2OTA1LCJqdGkiOiJpZDEyMzQ1NjgifQ.HI_IJ45KyaB8X7lVNhF4bJA60A_FZVsDW8vt8fT36iMb7Ikjw4pjbdIBAUMvF4PT72cpqlP3kWEi9mqJBPel7KrI9X94CaPMMWtV5MAPD674ZG-Rid3R8v-DjaMx5sgb6kR70cBNjMkib4SqfKvgOW7_oaIpUCcBAOFnqBjL44cCTEUlrSWK0vReaeJhNxLhb9a8diOnuBLI67bkSH0GriTGUcHxZC9NF5tWzHBXtzMFWLvX1_GwuBJOdhxGfyQ2qZpsYk6bi2nwApURVwetb192J37sGP5UP198Suz0rkylSaZClueWpwsU8QqltO3uK3mb1ASI4CTCjdJul_V7Gc8r42P2u_Z_jr8DsglfCtkFxepvF6nW4HvEDfED7FTmPPQ2f7V6W_zck4Il2_o6z3uEGxruXLL1KGjXw8cDFu22UZg2DFOBsGQz2OuKxCajYufriMBJy92BR4f32uaT7OpJwVJ3kcgzjV52KJrl5zq6M3U76VPZ0BSkgQd7tmqqYvH2gKUPUl_hZea5a7OhUi5hqIcLXfJ01vAeDgdRCJWHyO1Yq2tTntnSLiRVW71mKYowIKspZFW2erhbVV3bBih9BZGIXxPYkGciWvEw6FlNKQirE4PrSSrCclMW_lZV_UxmQw0LUeBnxDLEjnHuRTtrhu8SoTac04ZumSJHWX4).

When clicked, this decoding of the token will be shown:

[image]